# h:commandlink como botón que ejecute una acción

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa

Quiero que el commandlink funcione como un botón que se ejecute en la misma pagina, he intentado hacer click en el link de eliminar pero no pasa nada, todo lo demás funciona, solo eso es lo que me falta:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

<h:head></h:head>

<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>

    <h:form>
        <h2>Mantenimiento de Empleado</h2>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">       
            <h:outputText value="Nombre:"/>
            <h:inputText
             value="#{empleadoManagedBean.empleado.nombre}">
             </h:inputText>

             <h:outputText value="DNI:"/>
            <h:inputText
             value="#{empleadoManagedBean.empleado.dni}">
             </h:inputText>

             <h:outputText value="Fecha Nacimiento:"/>
             <h:inputText value="#{empleadoManagedBean.empleado.fechaNacimiento}" >
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"></f:convertDateTime>
             </h:inputText>


                 <h:outputText value="Sueldo:"/>
            <h:inputText
             value="#{empleadoManagedBean.empleado.sueldo}">
             </h:inputText>

              <h:outputText value="Departamento:"/>
              <h:selectOneMenu value="#{empleadoManagedBean.empleado.departamento.id}">
              <f:selectItems value="#{empleadoManagedBean.departamentos}"
                var="x" itemLabel="#{x.nombre}" itemValue="#{x.id}">

              </f:selectItems>

              </h:selectOneMenu>



    </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Registrar" 
        action="#{empleadoManagedBean.guardar}" ajax="false" />     



<h:dataTable value="#{empleadoManagedBean.empleados}" 
        var="e" border="1"  paginator="true" rows="5" >
<h:column headerText="Id">
        <h:commandLink value="#{e.id}" action="#{empleadoManagedBean.editar}">
            <f:param name="empleadoId" value="#{e.id}"></f:param>
        </h:commandLink>    
        </h:column>
<h:column headerText="Nombre">
            #{e.nombre}
        </h:column>

        <h:column headerText="DNI">
            #{e.dni}
        </h:column>


        <h:column headerText="Fecha de Nacimiento">
        <h:outputText value="#{e.fechaNacimiento}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"></f:convertDateTime>

        </h:outputText> 

        </h:column>


        <h:column headerText="Sueldo">
            #{e.sueldo}
        </h:column>

        <h:column headerText="Departamento">
            #{e.departamento.nombre}
        </h:column>

        <h:column headerText="Accion">
            <h:commandLink  value="Eliminar" action="#{empleadoManagedBean.eliminar}">
            <f:param name="empleadoId" value="#{e.id}"></f:param>
        </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>
</h:dataTable>

</h:form>   

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no utilizas mejor los componentes de PrimeFaces?

Comment: cual es tu solucion?

Comment: ¿No has intentado utilizar <p:commandLink...?

Comment: ya lo hice, sigue igual

Comment: ¿Y el método `eliminar()` no podría ser el error?

Comment: no porque cuando lo uso como commandbutton si elimina

Comment: Y si le colocas el atributo process="@this" al p:c ommandLink

Comment: no, tampoco sirve

Comment: ¿El bean que utiliza qué scope tiene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h:form>
    // ... 
 <h:column headerText="Accion">
   <h:commandLink  value="Eliminar" action="#{empleadoManagedBean.eliminar}">
        <f:param name="empleadoId" value="#{e.id}"></f:param>
   </h:commandLink>
 </h:column>
```

Si se refiere a que el botón "eliminar" actualice la información de la tabla al hacer click después de haber realizado algún trabajo del lado del servidor (eliminar una entidad Empleado) pues sí sería lógico que si **ya** está utilizando Primefaces pues que lo utilice en los botones que requira `AJAX`.

Ahora, normalmente cuando se utiliza ajax, es recomendado que el Backing Bean tenga un scope de `@ViewScoped` bien sea de scope CDI,ManagedBean o cual sea la tecnología que esté utilizando.

Primefaces utiliza ajax por defecto en los componentes de tipo `command***`, si por algún motivo no quiere utilizar PM, (asumiendo que utiliza JSF version 2.*) JSF tiene un componente `<f:ajax` para realizar llamados asíncronos al servidor por lo que podría cambiarlo a:

```
<h:commandLink  value="Eliminar" action="#{empleadoManagedBean.eliminar}">
   <f:param name="empleadoId" value="#{e.id}"></f:param>
   <f:ajax render="@form" />
</h:commandLink>
```

El `render="@form"` lo que hace es actualizar el formulario, que en éste caso contiene la tabla, con eso debería "desaparecer" la fila *eliminada*.

Adivinando un poco el método `eliminar`:

```
public String eliminar(){
  Map<String, String> parametros = (Map<String, String>) externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();

  String param = parametros.get("empleadoId");   

   servicioEmpleado.eliminarPorId(Integer.valueOf(param));

  return ""; o return null;
}
```

Por cierto, `return "";` refresca la vista, `return null; o void` no.

Tenga en cuenta que también es posible agregarle argumentos a los métodos que son llamados por un Facelet, con eso se ahorra un poco de tiempo y se vé un poco más claro el código:

public String eliminar(Integer id){

```
  servicioEmpleado.eliminarPorId(Integer.valueOf(param));

  return ""; o return null;
```

}

Y en el Facelet:

```
<h:commandLink  value="Eliminar" action="#{empleadoManagedBean.eliminar(e.id)}">
   <f:ajax render="@form" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Para mí, la mejor opción sería:

```
<p:commandLink value="Eliminar" action="#{empleadoManagedBean.eliminar(e.id)}" />
```